# Thread multiple parameters through a number of promises (bluebird)

Tags: javascript, bluebird

I want to thread a number of parameters through a chain of promises using sequelize / bluebird. To illustrate I have something like the following

```
asyncCreateA(function(a) {
    return [a, ayncCreateB(a)];
}).spread(function(a, b) {
    return [a, b, asyncCreateC(a, b)];
}).spread(function(a, b, c) {
    return doSomethingWith(a,b,c);
});
```

My question: Is it OK to use an array to return a mix of values and promises (I am using bluebird as a promise library if that matters)? Is there a more elegant/better way to do this?

Comment: Does your posted code actually work? How can you go from an array to the argument list? Isn't `a` the array, and `b` and `c` undefined?

Comment: @sebnukem [spread](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#spreadfunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler----promise).

Comment: @Paul cool thanks. Learned something new today.

Comment: It works in the sense that node doesn't give me direct errors in the code I posted. It doesn't do what I want (not sure if this is due to the construct above or something unrelated, hence the question).